# Simple WYSIWYG input for Drupal input

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg

I want to add basic WYSIWYG functionality to Drupal 6. It does not have to be bleeding edge. 
I have found about 150 blogs and posts with options and an equal about of issues and problems

Can somebody point me to the easiest solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working with this combination of modules.

- TinyTiny MCE  – text editor
- Tiny MCE - js
- IMCE – image uploader

I had a good blog with the recipe for setup, but can't find it today. :(

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution IMO is to use the [WYSIWYG api](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) to include TinyMCE.

You will need:

- [WYSIWYG dev release](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/wysiwyg-7.x-2.x-dev.tar.gz) (supports new TinyMCE)
- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php) main package

The WYSIWYG module has an excellent administration screen to which you can turn buttons on and off with a simple tick box. I also prefer TinyMCE due to it's small library and therefore fast speed on browsers.

For file uploading and integration with the WYSIWYG, I use:

- [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce)
- [IMCE Wysiwyg bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg)

Which I find super easy, and business users seem to have no issues either. Supports image resizing and thumbnail generation

Answer (score 1):

FCKeditor has been deprecated in favor of [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).  CKEditor also has a pay-for file manager addon called [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/).

Answer (score 1):

**CKEditor** is a good choice.  CKEditer can integrate with **IMCE** for file uploading as well as **CKFinder**.

Answer (score 0):

FCKeditor and TinyMCE are both good, simple choices.

Comment: forgot to mention that I need integrated file upload as well.